# Cannot convert value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to expected argument type 'User'

Tags: swift, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set "current" from my User Model so that I can later user current.username or current.uid, etc. however I am getting the "Cannot convert value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to expected argument type 'User'" error. In a past project I was able to do this following a tutorial which is shown at the very bottom. The code I have now is shown above it. I have checked other questions related to this on stack overflow but couldn't find something that helped me.

(User Model)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase.FIRDataSnapshot

class User: Codable {

    let uid: String
    let username: String

    init(uid: String, username: String){
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
    }

    init?(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any],
            let username = dict[Constants.Dict.username] as? String
            else { return nil }

        self.uid = snapshot.key
        self.username = username
    }

    private static var _current: User?

    static var current: User {
        guard let currentUser = _current else {
            fatalError("Error: current user doesn't exist")
        }
        return currentUser
   }

    class func setCurrent(_ user: User, writeToUserDefaults: Bool = false) {
        if writeToUserDefaults {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: Constants.UserDefaults.currentUser)
            }
        }

        _current = user
    }
}
```

(Current project - LoginVC)

```
@objc func handleSignIn() {
    guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return 

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            --> --> ERROR HERE "user" !!
            User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Error logging in: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

(Updated Solution)

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { user, error in
        if user?.user != nil {

            let user = user!.user

            UserService.show(forUID: user.uid) { (user) in
                User.setCurrent(user!, writeToUserDefaults: true)

                self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
            ...
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you want to do this? If you ever want to get the currentUser that's signed into Firebase it's this `let user = Auth.auth().currentUser` if you want to change the user, the user you want to change to needs to authenticate anyway so you'll need to call the `Auth.auth().signIn` function. As a note, Firebase has a 'User' class which is different than your 'user' class. If you want to have your own, call it 'MyUser" instead.

Comment: If I have a current user I can retrieve other things like current.time or current.score. I am trying to make a current like I did with the previous project so it easy to retrieve things about the user from firebase.

Comment: I have a solution but before I post it there's a couple of additional questions; It's not stated but are you trying to use a Singleton pattern to handle the user information? I ask that because *UserService* looks like you are. Also, your comment is *so it easy to retrieve things about the user from firebase* but there's no code in your question that retrieves anything from Firebase, other than authenticating. If you can elaborate a bit, there may be a simple solution.

Comment: Yes. It is Singleton pattern. I have code in my UserService to retrieve data. I added my whole user model above.

Comment: I've been looking at this code for a while and it seems overly complex if you just want a singleton available throughout your app to access user information. It's also unclear what's expected when `current` is called - it returns User but for what purpose? In other words if you want the current username or uid wouldn't it be simpler to use `let name = User.shared.name` or `let uid = User.shared.uid`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you just messed two different methods. In your past project it was method of **FirebaseUI-iOS**:

```
func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?)
```

from protocol "FUIAuthDelegate".

By the way, this method declared as "deprecated" now in [firebase sources](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/Auth/FirebaseAuthUI/FUIAuth.h):

```
- (void)authUI:(FUIAuth *)authUI
    didSignInWithUser:(nullable FIRUser *)user
                error:(nullable NSError *)error
__attribute__((deprecated("Instead use authUI:didSignInWithAuthDataResult:error:")));
```

As you can see, it has argument of type "FIRUser *" named "user".

But in current project you use method "signIn" of class "Auth" of **firebase-ios-sdk**. Let's look for signature of "signIn" in [sources of Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/53d7ee7c3e1d14c53e779d200b2617d763563b2c/Firebase/Auth/Source/Auth/FIRAuth.m):

```
    - (void)signInWithEmail:(NSString *)email
                   password:(NSString *)password
                 completion:(nullable FIRAuthDataResultCallback)completion {
```

[where "FIRAuthDataResultCallback" is](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuthDataResult.h):

```
/** @typedef FIRAuthDataResultCallback
    @brief The type of block invoked when sign-in related events complete.
    @param authResult Optionally; Result of sign-in request containing both the user and
       the additional user info associated with the user.
    @param error Optionally; the error which occurred - or nil if the request was successful.
 */
typedef void (^FIRAuthDataResultCallback)(FIRAuthDataResult *_Nullable authResult,
                                          NSError *_Nullable error)
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(AuthDataResultCallback);
```

so it has FIRST argument of type "FIRAuthDataResult *" named "authResult" (naming of closure arguments not preserved in modern Swift!). You named this argument "user" and made wrong assumption about it type - User.

What is "FIRAuthDataResult *"? [Let's look to sources once more](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Auth/Source/Public/FIRAuthDataResult.h):

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(AuthDataResult)
@interface FIRAuthDataResult : NSObject

/**...*/
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

/** @property user
    @brief The signed in user.
 */
@property(nonatomic, readonly) FIRUser *user;

/** @property additionalUserInfo
    @brief If available contains the additional IdP specific information about signed in user.
 */
@property(nonatomic, readonly, nullable) FIRAdditionalUserInfo *additionalUserInfo;

@end
```

So this is just container for user and additional info.

I think, this is how should look your current code to be compileable:

```
@objc func handleSignIn() {
    guard let email = emailField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = passwordField.text else { return 

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: pass) { authDataResult, error in
        guard let authDataResult = authDataResult,
            let user = authDataResult.user,
            error == nil else {
            print("Error logging in: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no description")")
            return
        }
        User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I did not really try to compile it!

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the explanation. I appreciate it. Although I am getting an error "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'User'" for the let user = authDataResult.user part

Comment: Try to remove this line completely: `let user = authDataResult.user,`. And rewrite this: `User.setCurrent(user, writeToUserDefaults: true)` with `User.setCurrent(authDataResult.user, writeToUserDefaults: true)`.

Comment: For that new User.setCurrent..."Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type 'User'" I am confused by this error because they're both type 'User'.

Comment: In current project you declared `class User: Codable {`. So method `class func setCurrent(_ user: User, writeToUserDefaults: Bool = false) {` - awaits your `User`. But `authDataResult.user` is really `FIRUser*`. So seems in your past project was magic in line `UserService.show(forUID: user.uid) { (user) in`. I can make assumtion, that it worked so: it got argument `user.uid` where `user` of type `FIRUser *` and `uid` of type `String`, then it called completion `{ (user) in` and in this point `user` already was of your `User` type. So let search there for hidden coversion `FIRUser *` to `User`.